Unexpected asymptotic logarithm behavior
I have recently seen a rather confusing asymptotic property of logarithms:
$$
\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq O(\log(n^3 + n^2 + n))
$$
I find this very unintuitive. Why would the log of a bigger polynomial be smaller than the log of a smaller polynomial? Both are monotonically increasing functions, after all.
Furthermore, the proof presented states
$
\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq \log(3n^4) $,  which makes sense, but seems to express the exact opposite intuition of the asymptote above - returning to a "bigger polynomial equals bigger log" reasoning.
I would appreciate a more generalized and if possible intuitive way of thinking about logarithms in this context. Any suggestions as to where my current interpretations might err are also appreciated.
EDIT:
Here the proof I'm presented with.
As $\log$ is monotone and $n^4 + n^3 + n^2 \leq 3n^4$, we have $$\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq \log(3n^4) = \log(3) + 4\log(n)$$
Now, $3 \leq n^3 + n^2 + n$ and $n^3 \leq n^3 + n^2 + n$, so we get $\log(3) \leq \log(n^3 + n^2 + n)$. Thus, we can conclude that $$4\log(n) = \frac{4}{3}\log(n^3) \leq \frac{4}{3}\log(n^3 + n^2 + n)$$
Therefore, $$\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq \log(3) + 4\log(n) \leq \frac{7}{3}\log(n^3 + n^2 + n)$$ which means that $$\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq O(\log(n^3 + n^2 + n))$$

Can you share the details of this proof? Also, is the big O notation in front of the log a typo or is it an algorithmics question?

Additionally, I originally tried proving this via applying the exponential function to both sides, but this ended up expressing the exact opposite of LHS $\geq$ RHS. A quick note on why this does not work would be helpful as well.

@RedFive Added the proof. This is supposed to be big O notation.

Thanks - thought so, but always good to check.

The point is that the left logarithm is at most the right logarithm multiplied by a constant which may be greater than 1.

When we take $\log_2( n^k)$ for any fixed $k>0$, then, obviously, as $\log_2( n^k)=k\cdot \log_2 n$, we actually have linear function from $\log$. This gives, that for any fixed $k_1>0,k_2>0$ we have
$$\log_2( n^{k_1}) = O(\log_2( n^{k_2}))=O(\log_2 n)$$
Let me say at end, that while the first equality above means membership, meanwhile the second is equality between sets.
I hope you are able to find out yourself,  that the remaining terms of sum do not change the result.

Ahhh, so this would imply that $ O(\log(n^k)) $ is the same for all $k$?

Of course. This is, so to speak, all the humor of this example.

We write $f(n) \le \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ iff there exists a (positive?) real number $c$ such that for sufficiently large $n$, $f(n) \le cg(n)$.
The property of logarithms which, along with the above definition, makes this asymptotic behaviour possible is that $c\log(x) = \log(x^c)$
Now with $c = 2$, it shouldn't be hard to see that
$$\log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \le 2\log(n^3 + n^2 + n) = \log([n^3 + n^2 + n]^2)$$
Edit: An attempt to provide intuition as below:
The reason this seems weird is that unlike with polynomial functions, scaling logarithms in some sense also scales the "degree" of your input. For example, doubling a quadratic polynomial still leaves you with a quadratic polynomial but doubling the log of a quadratic polynomial leaves you with the log of a quartic polynomial.
Hope it helps!

Couldn't we prove that $ \log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq 6 \log(n + 1) $ as well as $ \log(n^4 + n^3 + n^2) \leq 6 \log(n^5 + 1) $ are both true this way? This seems odd.

Yes we could prove that and it does feel odd, perhaps due to what I've written at the end of the answer.
